# How to save image source in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have created WPF Application in which when user will select an image and save it, it will be applied to all buttons, navigation bar items etc. I wrote code to save image path in `Settings.settings` File. As i select image it save this to database but not apply to `navigation bar items or buttons source of image` until i restart my application.
Here my code is:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : DXWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Refreshicon();
        }

        public void Refreshicon()
        {
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ApplicationSettings.Default.ImageName));  //Image From Settings File!
            MessageBox.Show("Image Path" + bi.ToString());
            navBarGroup1.ImageSource = bi;
            navBarGroup2.ImageSource = bi;
            navBarItem1.ImageSource = bi;
            navBarItem2.ImageSource = bi;
        }
```

How can i apply user defined image path to`navigation bar items or buttons` without restarting my application?

**Edit**
//This below code is to save image and to call `Refreshicon()` function

```
 private void Button_Click_SaveImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        string imagepath = ApplicationSettings.Default.ImageName;
        ApplicationSettings.Default.SetImage(imageEdit1.ImagePath);
        MainWindow a = null;
        if (a == null)
            {
            a=new MainWindow();
            a.Refreshicon();

            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you using application settings or user settings of application they will not get loaded except at start of application. If you want them to be used in the current application without restarting use user settings

Comment: Thank's. but How to to use this @MarkHall

Comment: I am using `User` `in Scope` in Application Settings.

Comment: That is what I was asking. You should be able to  do what you want along as it is user scoped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to call your `Refreshicon()` method in whatever code is writing the image path to the `Settings.settings` file.

Edit:

If `Button_Click_SaveImage` is in a window other than the `MainWindow`, then you need to add a reference to the original `MainWindow` instance to the child window class and call its `Refreshicon()` method.  Something like this:

In the child window class, let's call it DialogWindow:

```
public class DialogWindow : Window {
    // All your code here . . .

    public MainWindow Parent { get; set; }

    private void Button_Click_SaveImage( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
        // Your code up to the MainWindow a line goes here
        Parent.Refreshicon();
    }
}
```

Then, in `MainWindow`, when you instantiate the child window for display:

```
DialogWindow childWindow = new DialogWindow();
childWindow.Parent = this;
```

Comment: Yes this is what i am doing. i call this method but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I need more information to figure out what you need to do.  Would you please show the code that's writing the image path to the `Settings.settings` file?

Comment: The local `MainWindow` variable is the problem.  You are creating a new instance of the MainWindow class & calling `Refreshicon` on that.  The new instance has the changes that you're trying to make visible in the existing instance.  Get rid of the a variable, and instead of calling `a.Refreshicon()`, call `Refreshicon()` or `this.Refreshicon()`.

Comment: Hi thank's but i am using this button click event handler in an other xaml window. As i make changes what you has recommended it says: `Error 2 'WpfApplication7.IconImage' does not contain a definition for 'Refreshicon' and no extension method 'Refreshicon' accepting a first argument of type 'WpfApplication7.IconImage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\\Newfolder\WpfApplication7\WpfApplication7\IconImage.xaml.cs 62 22 WpfApplication7
`

Comment: I did not know that you were trying to call the `Refreshicon()` from another window.  It wasn't clear in your question. See the edits to my answer.

Comment: Thank's God! That Works! Thank's for answer  Tony Vitabile! :)